# How to see output of TextOutW(...) after each call?

Tags: visual-c++

On writing to the display with:

```
::TextOutW( pDC->m_hDC, x, y, &Out, 1 );
```

It only shows on the screen after every 15 calls (15 characters).
For debugging purposes only, I would like to see the new character on the display after each call. I have tried ::flushall() and a few other things but no change.
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDI function calls are accumulated and called in batches for performance reasons.
You can  call [`GdiFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144844%28VS.85%29.aspx) after the TextOut call to perform the drawing immediately. Alternatively, call [GdiSetBatchLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144846%28VS.85%29.aspx)(1) before outputting the text to disable batching completely.

Comment: Nice answer. Beat me by 45 seconds... :-)

Comment: Thank you much!
They both do what I want.
BTW, I tried setting other values in GdiSetBatchLimit(); and found that 15 seems to be the max. Higher values batch only 15 and lower values act as expected. The docs say a value of 0 sets the default.

Answer (score 1):

`::flushall()` is for iostreams, so it won't affect Windows screen output at all. I've never tried it, but based on the docs, I believe `GDIFlush()` might be what you want. You should also be able to use `GDISetBatchLimit(1);` to force each call to run immediately upon being called.

Comment: Thank you much! They both do what I want. That should be:
GdiSetBatchLimit(1); and GdiFlush();